# Binary clock for top menu bar - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, clock

As the title ambiguously suggests, I am looking for a binary clock for the top menu bar, similar to what is available for Xfce and Gnome desktops.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance to anyone who bothers to take time out of their day for this unessential cosmetic issue.

Comment: +1.  I've really appreciated it on XFCE.  Wish I could indeed get it on Unity.

Comment: You can get it in Dash Home...  But that's not fabulous.

Comment: The other possibility is to run a gnome panel with the clock at the bottom right of your screen or something.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, this will do what you want: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/46/binary-clock/